# Export / sync shared ’Public’ Facebook events from our Facebook Page with external calendar

Tags: google-calendar, facebook-pages, export, synchronization, facebook-events

We set up a Google calendar for our community years ago and it has proved to be a useful resource for many, especially those who do not use Facebook for whatever reason. However over the past few years Facebook has grown in popularity and the majority of information we list on our Google calendar actually comes from Facebook groups containing Facebook events or posts with “flyer” images.

I’ve been trying to figure out a straightforward way to get various Facebook events into our Google calendar and to automate the process and searching this website I came across a really promising script found at the following question/answer by Jobjörn Folkesson:

[Exporting Facebook page events to Google Calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29136/exporting-facebook-page-events-to-google-calendar/122877?noredirect=1#comment111022_122877)

This seemed like a really good contender and could potentially hold the key to pull Facebook event data into our Google calendar via an .ICS file.  However it seems the issue is that Facebook have now restricted their API in such a way it appears quite tricky to to pull ‘Public’ event data even when it's shared to a Facebook page we own and manage.

Given that we are dealing with data that is in the ‘Public’ domain I don't see why it shouldn't be possible to pull this from my own page, but sadly the script in the link above only pulls events from my page that I created personally. Is there a way to adopt the script created by Jobjörn or is there another way of pulling (or syncing) public event data from my Facebook page?